# Prove the inverse of this differentiable function is differentiable?

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives

Suppose we have a differentiable function $ g $ that maps from a real interval $ I $ to the real numbers and suppose $ g'(r)>0$ for all $ r$ in $ I $. 
Then I want to show that $ g^{-1}$ is differentiable on $g(I). $

Intuitively this makes sense but I can't come up with a neat proof. I was thinking to use the mean value theorem but I'm not sure if that would get me anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition of derivative we have

$$g'(r)=\lim_{x\to r}\frac{g(x)-g(r)}{x-r}=\lim_{x\to r}\frac{g(x)-g(r)}{g^{-1}(g(x))-g^{-1}(g(r))}$$

Since $g'(r)>0$, this means

$$\lim_{x\to r}\frac{g^{-1}(g(x))-g^{-1}(g(r))}{g(x)-g(r)}=\frac{1}{g'(r)}$$

Let $y\in g(I)$, say $g(x)=y$ for some $x\in I$, and let $y_n\to y$. Then for each $n$ there is a unique $x_n\in I$ with $g(x_n)=y_n$. Further, one can show that if $f$ is continuous and strictly monotone on an interval $I$, then $f^{-1}$ is continuous on $f(I)$, hence we have $x_n\to x$, it follows that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g^{-1}(y_n)-g^{-1}(y)}{y_n-y}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n-x}{g(x_n)-g(x)}=\frac{1}{g'(x)}$$

Hence $g^{-1}$ is differentiable.

Comment: "Hence" is not fully justified; the last limit you wrote is not exactly the same as the definition of derivative.

Comment: Why can we say that $ x-r $ is the same thing as $ g^{-1}(g(x))-g^{-1}(g(r)) $? does injectivity have anything to do with this

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Good point, I've added more details

Comment: @Rina I've added more details in my answer

Comment: thanks Frank! this clears up a lot

Comment: what is the purpose of mentioning the sequences?

Comment: there is also a sequence version of continuity criterion: $f$ is continuous at a point $x$ if and only if for every sequence $(x_n)$ in the domain with $x_n\to x$ we have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. And one can deduce a similar criterion for differentiability. The point is the limit of a continuous function can always interchange with the limit of corresponding sequences

Answer (score -1):

If $g'(r)>0$ then $g(r)$ in injective.

Exist $g^{-1}(r)$.

Then use the chain rule for derivate $g^{-1}(g(r))=r$.

Comment: This is true; but how would that help prove the claim?

Comment: I see; what role does injectivity play? Why does $ g^{-1}(r) $ exist

Comment: @Rina: A function has a (set-theoretic) inverse precisely when it's injective and surjective. Since a function $f : A\to B$ always surjects onto its image $im(f)$, there will be an inverse $f^{-1} : im(f)\to A$ precisely when $f$ is injective.

Comment: oh okay got it. thanks a lot

Comment: To apply the chain rule to the composition $g^{-1}\circ g$, one needs to know that both functions involved are differentiable. Which is to be proved.

Comment: that's what I was thinking actually; because we haven't shown that $ g^{-1} $ is differentiable

Comment: the identity is differentiable